To what does this それ refer?
I wonder what the それ means in this sentence:
親が心配してその寮をみつけてきてくれた。そこなら食事もついているし、いろんな設備も揃っているし、世間知らずの十八の少年でもなんとか生きていけるだろうということだった。もちろん費用のこともあった。寮の費用は一人暮しのそれに比べて格段に安かった。
I initially thought it can be replaced by 費用, but I'm not really sure.

I think you are correct!

On a second read, it looks correct.

You are correct, this それ refers to 費用:

寮の費用は一人暮しのそれに比べて格段に安かった。
The dormitory cost was significantly cheaper compared to that of living alone.

Note that, in Japanese, it's more common to simply say 寮の費用は一人暮らしと比べて格段に安かった. Please read this discussion.
